# Start tag "a" seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html, I try to put a link("a"), a text "b", and a link "c" together in the same line. Here is my code.

```
<a class = "fixed" href="/a/">linka <span> b </span> <span> <a href="/c/">linkc </a> </span> </a>
```

But I got some errors, like:

> Start tag "a" seen but an element of the same type was already open.
> error: End tag "a" violates nesting rules.
> error: Stray end tag "span".
> error: Stray end tag "a".

I try to get rid of nested , but the linkC would not show up. How to fix this error?

Comment: You're resting anchors, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

This error ish happening because you have a `<a>` tag nested within the first `<a>` tag, which is not allowed in **HTML**. To achieve the layout you're looking for, you can use a different approach that doesn't involve nesting `<a>` tags.

One way you could fix this is to use a container element, such as a `<div>`, to wrap all the elements together.

**Example:**

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <a href="/a/">linka</a> 
  <span> b </span> 
  <a href="/c/">linkc </a> 
</div>
```